# How to reduce space between elements on a row in css bootsrap?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Can someone help me to reduce the extra space between the fields (Site ID and Switch) on my django form below? I am using bootstrap, css and html. I am new to CSS/Bootstrap therefore any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Here is code:

````
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}

<br>
<br>
<div class="row form-row spacer rootrow" style="width: 700px; padding: 0; margin: left;" id = "id_parent">
    <div class="col">
        <!-- <label>{{form.name.label}}</label> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col"  style="width: 25px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 1300px; height: 20px;"> <!--this style= width value changes the width of the form row-->
        <div class="input-group">
            
   
       

        {% for field in form %}

        <div class="col-auto">
                                <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}" >{{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}*{% endif %}</label>

        </div>
     
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-control"style="padding: 0;">
                

                    {% ifequal field.name 'site' %}
                            {% render_field field class="dropdownlistener" required=true  %}
    
                        {% endifequal %}                               </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control"style="padding: 0;">
                
                    {% ifequal field.name 'switch' %}

                    {% render_field field class="dropdownforswitch" required=true %}

                {% endifequal %}               
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **col-md** or **col-sm** from bootstrap like following and manage space between fields using padding and margin

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please refer this site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Can you please share a sample of what you're suggesting? I tried to replace the lines before the "render" code but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Use following grid system

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
            <label>Label1</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
            <label>Label2</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-12">Label3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
            <label>Label4</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```